# Not matching available overloads error with ioscharts

Tags: swift, xcode, bar-chart, ios-charts

I want to set up bar charts with Swift 3 and follow [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-charts-api-tutorial/) tutorial.

I created a `barChartView` within my `viewController` and the data values in `viewDidLoad`:

```
var months: [String]!
var counts: [Double]!
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
counts = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
```

Then I call the `setChart` function with the values:

```
setChart(dataPoints: months, values: counts)
```

The function itself looks as follows:

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
      let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
      dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
    countPerCountryView.data = chartData
}
```

I am getting two error warnings when trying to build, here:

```
let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
Argument labels '(value:, xindex:)' do not match any available overloads
```

and here:

```
let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'BarChartData' with an argument list of type '(xvals: [String]!, dataSet: BarChartDataSet)'
```

Comment: Why do you declare non-optional constants (`months` and `counts`) as implicit unwrapped optional variables?? If they were supposed to be variables, declare them at least as non-optional arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS-Chart has had some changes:

1. `BarChartDataEntry(value:xIndex:)` was changed to  `BarChartDataEntry(x: y:)`
2. `BarChartData(xVals: dataSet:)` was changed to `BarChartData(dataSet:)`

So you need something like this

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
      let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i])
      dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    countPerCountryView.data = chartData
}
```

Also if you want to set labels for xAxis you need to implement `IAxisValueFormatter` protocol with method `stringForValue( _: axis:)`
You can do it in your ViewController, for example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, IAxisValueFormatter {

    // your code ...

    // implement delegate method
    func stringForValue(_ dataPointIndex: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        return someDataPoints[Int(dataPointIndex)]
    }

    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]){
        // your code ...

        // Set delegate 
        lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    }

    // your code ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Wasn't aware of the changes

Answer (score 2):

Charts 3.0 has some breaking changes. Try this

```
class BarChartViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        barChartView.delegate = self
        barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = self

        let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
        setChart(values: unitsSold)
    }

    func setChart(values: [Double]) {
        barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

        let chartData = BarChartDataSet()
        for (i, val) in values.enumerated(){
            _ = chartData.addEntry(BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: val))
        }
        barChartView.data = BarChartData(dataSet: chartData)
    }
}

extension BarChartViewController: IAxisValueFormatter{
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        return months[ Int(value) % months.count]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a More Updated Answer :-) Thanks